# Hotel de Ville during Women's March on Versailles

Tags: french-revolution

What is the present location of the Hotel de Ville where women congregated just before the March on Versailles to take the king to Paris? Specifically, where they met with Mirabeau, Robespierre, etc

Answer (score 1):

The Hotel de Ville was then located at the same spot as it is now. I presume you know where this is. The original building burnt down during the Commune, but it was rebuilt on the same site.

Comment: Is it the Mairie de Versailles building or Hotel Des Menus Plaisirs? The Mairie de Versailles appears to be the Hotel de Ville but during my research I have read it was the Hotel Des Menus Plaisirs where the women actually met. I've seen conflicting information.

Comment: @Zoe Welcome to History:SE. If you have conflicting sources, please cite them in your question. It makes it much easier for people to answer your question if we know exactly what you are asking about.

Comment: @Zoe The women congregated in the  [Hotel de Ville](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B4tel_de_Ville,_Paris) of Paris, although I never heard that they met there with Robespierre or Mirabeau. It is not in Versailles, the march started in the markets of the Faubourg Saint Antoine, in Paris.

Comment: @CGCampbell. I don't understand your last sentence. Is there something missing?

Comment: @fdb I'm new to this site, but it seems to me that the OP's problem is that s/he imagines that the Hôtel de Ville was located in Versailles. This is obviously not the case, but I think it should be addressed in the answer (possibly by saying that the Hôtel de Ville is located in what is now the 4th arrondissement of Paris, or by some other geographical indication)